# jenkins pipeline didn't get slave environment variable

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

i have an issue with my groovy code in jenkins.

On my jenkins i configured global variable called "X" with the value "x",
than i configured linux slave and set to the slave private environment variable with the same key ("X") and set different value "xx".

than in order to test if the private environment variable override the global on i create two jobs:

1. freestyle job - in the build configuration i execute shell with the command "echo $X" and i get the "xx" as excepted.
2. pipeline job - on there i configured the following code:

   ```
   `node('master'){
       stage("master running") {
           println("run in master node.")
           println(env.X)
       }
   }

   node("slave") {
       stage("slave running") {
           println("run in slave node.")
           println(env.VAULT_URL)
           echo "${VAULT_URL}"
       }
   }`
   ```

and i get the global environment value, i get the x and not the xx.
someone know why on freestyle project the private slave environment variable are set and on pipeline job it did not?

Comment: I want to leave a note to save some time of those who stumble over this question.

This is a reported and until today(March 2020) still unreasolved Jenkins bug. 

You may check the resolution status by following this link:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44425 https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44465

If the bug is fixed, please ignore this comment.